# NodeJS PostgresSQL array of numbers treated as strings in WHERE IN clause

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I want to have the IN clause in my where query but for whatever reason, NodeJS treats it as an array of strings.

```js
      pool.query(`SELECT count(*)
                  FROM ${dbConfig.schema}.orders
                  WHERE 1=1
                  AND order_number IN ($1)
                  AND id_user <> $2`
                , [req.body, req.userId])
              .then(data => {
                res.status(200).send(data.rows)
                next()
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                console.log(req.body)
              })
```

Output:

```
error: invalid input syntax for type bigint: "{"20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40"}"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage ...
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:302:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:278:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:217:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
  length: 197,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '22P02',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'int8.c',
  line: '126',
  routine: 'scanint8'
}
[
  20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26,
  27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
  34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40
]
```

as you can see, it says:
`invalid input syntax for type bigint: "{"20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40"}"`

but I am sending in:
`[ 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40 ]`

any idea what is going on? am I missing something?

Comment: I can't help you with the parameter being incorrectly sent by the library, but your query has a mistake. The `order_number IN ($1)` should be `order_number = ANY ($1)` to make it work with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that `UNNEST` solved the problem. It should be that `req.body` is not instance of array but is a string. This maybe solved by configuring `bodyParser`, or it may be issue with request you send.

If you aren't willing to configure `bodyParser` for the app, simply adding `JSON.parse` should solve your problem:

```
pool.query(`SELECT count(*)
                  FROM ${dbConfig.schema}.orders
                  WHERE 1=1
                  AND order_number IN ($1)
                  AND id_user <> $2`
                , [JSON.parse(req.body), req.userId])
              .then(data => {
                res.status(200).send(data.rows)
                next()
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                console.log(req.body)
              })
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, UNNEST solved my problem ... leaving this for the others

```js
    pool.query(`SELECT count(*)
                  FROM ${dbConfig.schema}.customer_phone_map
                  WHERE 1=1
                  AND phone_number IN (SELECT UNNEST($1::int[]))
                  AND id_user <> $2`
                , [req.body, req.userId])
              .then(data => {
                res.status(200).send(data.rows)
                next()
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                console.log(req.body)
              })
```